# Fast way to compute only the diagonal of the square of a matrix

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have an `nxm` matrix `V`, of which I compute the square `S=V'*V`. For my following computations I need only the diagonal of `S`, so I write `s=diag(V'*V)`. However, this is a bit of a waste, because I'm computing also all the off-diagonal elements. Is there a **fast** way to compute only the diagonal elements of `S`? I could use a `for` loop, of course, but explicit looping isn't the fast way to do stuff in MATLAB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's easy:

```
sum(conj(v).*v,1)
```

or

```
sum(abs(v).^2,1)
```

If the matrix is real, you can simplify to

```
sum(v.*v,1)
```

or

```
sum(v.^2,1)
```

Comment: :) thanks, man - I was sure this would be answered by you. You're my official `bsxfun` guru! I like the third one because it's basically the definition of matrix product. I actually needed the diagonal as a column vector, so I modifed it to `sum(v.*v,1)'`, but apart from that it was perfect!!

Comment: @DeltaIV Would be interesting to see how much faster that is compared to your original solution.

Comment: @DeltaIV Thanks! No `bsxfun` needed here, though :-)